# CSS Style Attributes

Tags: css

I have come across [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-css-style-attr-20131107/) while going over CSS specifications on W3C. Now according to wiki [page](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:CSS3_taxonomy_and_status_by_Sergey_Mavrody.svg), this is part of level 3. However, I have the following two questions

1. No where in the document it says it belongs to level 3. Does "style attributes" really belong to CSS level 3?
2. I did quite a bit of Googling for "style attributes" however I cannot find any articles to explain what exactly this document is about and how it differs from CSS2.1 to CSS3. Could somebody either explain to me the nature of this document or provide a link to an article that explains it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is related to css3. I think it's simply talking about inline styles.

We have internal, external and inline styles so this probably the 3rd one - inline.

http://www.expression-web-tutorial.com/Types_CSS_Styles.html#.Vip3XWcrJNA
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Answer (score 0):

Originally, the generation of *specifications* that came after CSS 2.1 was CSS 3. But whereas CSS 1 and 2 were monolithic, CSS 3 was modularized to allow different parts of specification to progress at their own rates. CSS Style attributes became one module within that.

Now, the point of modules progressing at their rates is that some parts will go through several generations, while during the same time, other parts will go through fewer or even none. So it makes little sense for the modules to refer to themselves as CSS 3 or 4 or whatever.

Instead, think of CSS 3 as an umbrella term to cover the CSS specifications in modular form. Each module in turn will have its own versioning, which may simply be the date of publication.